# Como hacer para que lo que se ingrese a un jtextField se agregue siempre en la primera posición en java?

Tags: java, string, jframe, jtextfield, caracteres

buenas tardes tengo un pequeño programa en jframeForm donde tengo 2 jlabels que muestran numeros al asar y un jtextfield donde se podrá ingresar el resultado de la suma de los dos label y lo mas natural seria que al ir ingresando los números siempre sea al inicio del lo que ya está tipeado, por ejemplo

jLabel1:   2156

jlabel2:   5124

---

txtField:     0   (primer caracter ingresado)

txtfield:    80    (segundo caracter ingresado)

txtfiekd:   280    (tercer caracter ingresado)

txtfield:  7280    (cuarto caracter ingresado)

entonces el primer carácter que ingrese seria: 0, que es la suma de 6 y 4
el segundo carácter que ingrese, se ingrese a la izquierda del cero: 80
el tercero seria a la izquierda del 8: 280
el cuarto y ultimo seria el siete a la izquierda del 2: 7280.

en otras palabras cada que vaya tipeando un carácter este siempre se agregue a la izquierda de lo que ya se tiene... se los agradecería demasiado!

Answer (score 0):

despues de buscar y rebuscar por todos lados, se m ocurrio hacer lo siguiente:
dentro del evento del JTextField donde ya tenia un *if* para que cuando se presionara la tecla *Enter* el foco se pasara al siguiente campo, a este if le añadí un else if para cuando se presionara una tecla diferente a *Escape, TAB y Retroceso* este caracter se ingresara en la posicion 0 con el metodo del JTextField *setCaretPosition(0)*, y el ultimo *else if* es para cuando se quisiera borrar, se borarra lo ultimo ingresado, siempre y cuando el campo no estuviera vacio:

```
private void txt1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            txt2.requestFocus();
        } else if (evt.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE && evt.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_TAB && evt.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
            txt1.setCaretPosition(0);
        } else if (!txt1.getText().isEmpty() && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
            txt1.setCaretPosition(1);
        }
    }
```